# Distributing balls to boxes with restrictions on boxes in which some of the balls may be placed

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $4$ balls of the 1st kind, $12$ balls of the 2nd kind and $3$ balls of the 3rd kind. There are $4$ boxes on a table. Balls of the 1st kind can be put only in 1st $2$ boxes and balls of 2nd kind can be put only in other $2$ boxes. Balls of 3rd kind can go in any box . In how many ways can the balls be put in these boxes? No two balls are same. Ordering of balls is not important.

I am able to place the 1st and 2nd kind of balls in respective boxes in $4C2 \cdot 12C2$ ways. But I'm not able to place 3rd kind of balls. How to include these balls? Proceeding with the most intuitive way creates a lot of cases which will not be effective if these numbers are large. Please suggest any effective method.

Thanks.

Comment: Please generalise the process of solving for larger no. of balls and boxes. 1st type of balls can be put in first n boxes and the 2nd type of balls can be put in the other n boxes out of 2n boxes.

Comment: Note that $\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of ways of selecting two balls from a collection of four balls.  What you need to count is the number of ways of distributing four balls of the first kind to two boxes.  If I understand you correctly, the balls are distinct, in which case you have two choices for each ball.  If balls of the same kind are not distinct, then the problem reduces to finding the number of balls in each box.  Are balls of the same kind distinct or indistinguishable?

Comment: All the balls are distinct. No two balls are same.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Since no two balls are the same, we have two choices for each of the four balls of the first kind.  Hence, they can be distributed in $2^4$ ways.  Similarly, we have two choices for each of the twelve balls of the second kind.  Hence, they can be distributed in $2^{12}$ ways.  However, we have four choices for each of the three balls of the third kind, so they can be distributed in $4^3$ ways.  Thus, the number of ways of distributing the three types of balls given the restrictions is 
$$2^4 \cdot 2^{12} \cdot 4^3 = 2^4 \cdot 2^{12} \cdot 2^6 = 2^{22}$$

Note that 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
is the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ objects from a set with $n$ objects.  Therefore, 
$$\binom{4}{2}$$
is the number of ways of selecting a subset of two of the four balls of the first kind, not the number of ways of distributing the balls of the first kind to two boxes. To verify that there are $2^4 = 16$ ways to distribute balls of the first kind to two boxes, we list the possibilities.  Let's call the four distinct balls of the first kind $a, b, c, d$.  Here are the possible distributions.
$$
\begin{array}{c | c}
\text{Box 1} & \text{Box 2}\\ \hline
a, b, c, d & \\
a, b, c & d\\
a, b, d & c\\
a, c, d & b\\
b, c, d & a\\
a, b & c, d\\
a, c & b, d\\
a, d & b, c\\
b, c & a, d\\
b, d & a, c\\
c, d & a, b\\
a & b, c, d\\
b & a, c, d\\
c & a, b, d\\
d & a, b, c\\
& a, b, c, d
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I answered the question you asked.

Comment: By this way, we are distributing all the balls. I need to find no. of ways to select 2 balls from 7 balls (4 balls of the 1st kind and 3 balls of the 3rd kind) and 2 balls from 15 balls(12 balls of the 1st kind and 3 balls of the 3rd kind) and place all the 4 selected balls in 4 different boxes. Only 1 ball can be placed in 1 box.

Comment: I apologise for the improper description of the question.

Comment: I see nine cases, depending on whether $0$, $1$, or $2$ balls of type 1 are used and whether $0$, $1$, or $2$ balls of type 2 are used.  For the case in which $1$ ball of type 1 is used and $2$ balls of type 2 are used, there are $2$ ways to choose which of the first two boxes receives a ball of type 1, $4$ ways to choose that ball, $3$ ways to choose which ball of type 2 goes in box 3, $2$ ways to choose which ball of type 2 goes in box 4, and $12$ ways to choose which ball of type 3 goes in the empty box.   That case gives $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 12 = 576$ possible distributions.